# Selecting text from react-select's valueComponent

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there any way to enable user select of text from selected value in react-select? No examples on http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/ seem to support that.

Comment: The lib doesn't let you do that. But u can probably show the selected text somewhere in the UI. That way u can select the text.

Comment: No default behavior on this lib. Maybe this will help https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1868#issuecomment-325952583